# "basculer de ... vers ...": Is this an acceptable structure?

Tags: prépositions

> Je n'utilise pas que le clavier AZERTY ou QWERTY. Je **bascule** **de** l'un **à**/**vers** l'autre quand bon me chante.

I just said this in conversation, but I wonder if "basculer de ... vers ..." is just as acceptable as "basculer de ... à ..."?

Comment: Exactly! As you said! *As acceptable as* !

Comment: @aCOSwt Curious. When you type text in French, do you plump for which style?

Comment: Eh... bien... tantôt l'un, tantôt l'autre... forcément. ;) En fait, si je prête attention à ce que je veux dire, **je** (me myself & I) préférerai de l'un **à** l'autre s'il y a contact physique ou adhésion avec une idée. Et **vers** si il n'y est question que d'approche, de direction, de sens. Sans contact ni adhésion. (Mais cela dit, I am possibly alone on that one)

Comment: This being said... as far as keyboards are concerned : AZERTY only! I need comfort with accents.

Comment: It’s not relevant to your interesting question (and it’s probably just me who’s not getting the full importance of your use of “ou” and not “et”), but the way the first sentence in your question is written made me think that you were possibly going to be mentioning in sentence two a third (or more) type(s) of keyboard(s) that you use in addition to the two mentioned earlier. Anyway, sentence two clarifies the meaning of sentence one, even for me!

Comment: @PapaPoule Hi. What I mean by the 1st sentence is essentially: "I don't stick to (just) one or the other; (I use them both)". :)

Comment: @PapaPoule : You are and correct and not alone ;) However the use of *et* would not solve the ambiguity. I looked at your profile, do you mean that you are **only** a husband *and* a father ? In order to solve the ambiguity, you'd need to be explicit about the fact that you use 2 keyboards : *J'utilise deux claviers. Un AZERTY et un QWERTY et bascule... *

Comment: @aCOSwt Thanks for suggesting that my comment wasn’t completely off base! Re your suggestion to explicitly state that one uses 2 keyboards, however, the OP’s profile temps me to believe that such a statement wouldn't be completely true (i.e., that OP uses more than 2 keyboards). That said, I do agree that OP could've been more explicit about the [non-exclusive] nature of the use in sentence one, & if s/he still wants to use the negative, maybe “"Je n'utilise exclusivement ni un [clavier] AZERTY ni QUERTY" (or some more natural way of including the “non-exclusive” nature of the use) would do.

Answer (score 2):

*Basculer* can be used with *vers* but not *à* so we say:

> ***Basculer vers*** le clavier qwerty

and not

> ***Basculer <s>au</s>*** clavier qwerty

On the other hand, both ***de x à y*** and ***de x vers y*** are possible.

In the first sentence, the move is completed (or is described as a whole) while in the second one, the move is ongoing. That doesn't make a significant difference when applying to keyboard settings so both forms are possible and acceptable.

We can also say:

> *Je bascule **d**'azerty **en** qwerty.*

I would use:

> *Je n'utilise pas qu'un seul type de clavier, azerty ou qwerty. Je passe de l'un à l'autre quand ça<sup>1</sup> me chante.*

<sup>1</sup><sub>*Quand bon me chante* sounds odd. It's usually either *quand bon me semble* or *quand ça me chante*</sub>

Comment: Oh, I see. How do you personally express the sentence I said?